# Undefined Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a way to multiply undefined matrices?

For example, how can I find product $AB$ of matrices
$\;\: A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \;\:$  and 
$\;\: B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There are (several) ways: one is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product. Another could be $AB:=A^ \top B$. But what is true, is that you cannot multiply them using "standard" matrix multiplication, as the dimensions don't allow it.

Comment: What do you mean by *undefined matrices*? Before you can define a multiplication operation for matrices, you must specify where the components of the matrices come from (which field, ring, or whatever).

Comment: The question you need to ask yourself is: Why do you want to multiply them? What should the result tell you?

Comment: These matrices are related to the spins of the electron.
I want to know whether these two matrices commute or not. In other words, if AB = BA ?

Comment: You should be looking instead at the matrices $AA^T$ and $BB^T$

Answer (score 0):

Try with the so-called tensor or kroenecker product. For the case you are stating in the question, the operation would be performed in the next way:
$A\otimes B = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1B  \\
a_2B\end{array} \right)=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 \\
1 \\
0\\
0\\ \end{array} \right)$

Comment: Thank you so much Josu Etxezarreta Martinez for your help...